# What exactly happened in this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have this integral
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ix}}{x^2+1}\,dx $$
where $i$ is an imaginary number.

On the book, the author procedes this way
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ix}}{x^2+1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{-\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{(-x)^2+1} \, d(-x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1} \, dx$$

It seems like he changed the sign of the variable but that implied him to change the sign of the limit of integration. The question is, am I allowed to do that? Or I'm just confused, and he did something else?

Obs: I understood the last step, he just changes the order of the limits and that implies on changing the signal of the integral so the signal become positive when multiplied by the signal of the $d(-x)$, right?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's like a substitution $u=-x$

Comment: Have you learned a substitution of the variable in an integral?

Comment: If you don't like $x=-x$ substitution use $x=-t$. As the integration variable is dummy in the end you can rename $t$ to $x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I actually thought it might be that, but at first it seemed wrong to me call $x=-x$. But now I see it was just something dummy.
Thanks a lot guys.